# Out of memory when use lambda expression

Tags: c#, oracle, lambda

I use lambda expression to query data, whenever i debug and view memory, memory continuous increase.It can reason make exception "System.OutOfMemoryException".How to clear cache memory whenever finish execute lambda expression?

```
public override IQueryable<TableA> GetList(Func<TableA, bool> conditon, bool isNoTracking = false)
{
    var result =  Context.TableA
        .Join(Context.TableB.AsNoTracking(), x => x.TYU_URICOMCODE, y => y.MACS_KOKYAKU_CODE, CreateOrder)
        .Where(conditon).AsQueryable();
    return result;        
}
```

Comment: What does `CreateOrder` do? Feels like a side-effect...

Comment: it is function with params (TableA a, TableB b) and return a after execute.

Comment: Are you *expecting* to fetch the entire table content into memory? Because that's what I believe is happening...

Answer (score 1):

I have a few suspicions:

1. Your `CreateOrder` side-effect is doing something that is using up memory. Remember it's running per-row returned.
2. You're inadvertently loading all rows from the database, then using the in-memory LINQ methods to join/filter it.
3. Note that in the database-specific flavour of LINQ, `.Where()` returns a `WhereIterator`, which is already queryable, so building a new queryable is unnecessary, and will also be doing memory allocations. If you're having to call `.AsQueryable()` to get it to compile, then you're almost certainly falling foul of suspicion #2 above.

Comment: The last point doesn't make sense to me - `AsQueryable` is almost certainly required here in order to make the code compile *because* of the first/second bullet. I'm pretty sure the return type of `Join` here is `IEnumerable<T>` for some `T`, which means the return type of `Where` will also be `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: Ugh, you're right. I didn't even make 3 a bullet until the last moment before I published the answer. It came from thinking about point 2. Maybe it should be 2a. :)